# How to wish someone "Happy New Year" in a professional, formal and friendly way

Tags: email, formality

English is my second language. I still struggle with it especially when I have to write a formal email.

I need to send an email to several of my business associates in reply to theirs. It contains some technical explanation related to our project, after which I would like to wish them *Happy New Year*. What is a professional, formal and friendly way to say this?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with a straightforward "Happy New Year". An exclamation point is optional, though since you did put in the word "professional" somewhere in your question...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about

> Dear X,
>
> Regarding the explanation of our project bla bla...
>
> And finally, 
>   Wish you and your family a
>   very Happy New Year.
>
> Looking forward to working with you next year.
>
> Regards,

or

> Dear X,
>
> Wish you and your family a
>   very Happy New Year.
>
> Regarding the project matter for discussion bla bla
>
> Regards,

Either of these should be fine. 
The reference to "family" or "loved ones" makes it less formal - but is still professional.

Comment: my email is not going to be like that. as explained in the question, it contains some technical discussion about project. i'd like to wish them after the discussion. is it still ok to wish using the style you've mentioned?

Comment: @Donotalo: Yes, and you could begin by wishing them rather than leave it for the end.

Comment: @Donotalo: You can append a "P.S. Happy New Year." after that long technical discussion you write...

Comment: "Wish you" (without a preceding pronoun) does not sound natural to my ear. It should be "We wish you" or "I wish you".

Comment: @Marthaª Sounds odd to me, too. Although, "Sounds odd" is missing the subject pronoun as well, and that sounds fine to me. What about "Wishing you"? That also sounds OK to me without the I or we.